# Android: how to initialize components in a subclass of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

### What I've done so far

I am brand new to Android.  I am trying to write a music theory app.  I want to write a subclass of `RelativeLayout` that includes a set of `ToggleButtons`.  The below code produces this screenshot (with four of the toggle buttons selected, which I achieved by pressing them in the UI; I didn't select them programmatically):

[image: Screenshot of my pitch selector fragment]

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


public class PitchSelectorView extends RelativeLayout {

    public static final String[] PITCH_NAMES = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F",
                                                "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"};
    public static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 100;
    public static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 100;
    public static final int CIRCLE_SIZE = 250;
    private ToggleButton[] buttons = new ToggleButton[PITCH_NAMES.length];

    public PitchSelectorView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public PitchSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public PitchSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }


    private void init(Context context) {
        double delta = Math.PI * 2 / buttons.length;
        double angle = -90.0;
        double x;
        double y;

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            angle += delta;
            x = (Math.cos(angle) * CIRCLE_SIZE) + CIRCLE_SIZE;
            y = (Math.sin(angle) * CIRCLE_SIZE) + CIRCLE_SIZE;

            ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(context);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pitch_button);
            button.setMinimumWidth(BUTTON_WIDTH * (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            button.setMinimumHeight(BUTTON_HEIGHT * (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            button.setWidth(BUTTON_WIDTH * (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            button.setHeight(BUTTON_HEIGHT * (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            String text = Integer.toString(i) + " " + PITCH_NAMES[i];
            button.setText(text);
            button.setTextOn(text);
            button.setTextOff(text);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
            if (layout == null) {
                layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }
            layout.leftMargin = (int) x;
            layout.topMargin = (int) y;

            buttons[i] = button;

            addView(button, layout);
        }
    }
}
```

### How to do it properly?

I am quite sure I haven't done this correctly.  I want to base the variables `BUTTON_WIDTH`, `BUTTON_HEIGHT`, and `CIRCLE_SIZE` off of the user's screen size, but the parent fragment's size is unavailable to me in the `init(context)` method.

I am not sure where I should be initializing my `ToggleButtons` and adding them to the `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out I was going about this all wrong.  What I need to do is subclass a ViewGroup to define how the child elements get arranged, then create the child elements and add them to the custom ViewGroup in my Activity (or I guess Fragment).  This tutorial helped me understand: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-a-custom-layout-in-android-by-extend